# Deixar últimos 12 registros e apagar o resto em PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Gostaria de fazer com que após executado o script, possa existir somente os últimos 12 registros em uma tabela especifica que tem o campo data em formato internacional se puder auxiliar.

```
<?php

# Este pequeno script PHP recupera o OD do imóvel visitado
# e o cadastra no banco de dados permitindo assim que o 
# módulo de ULTIMOS IMOVEIS VISUALIZADOS esteja sempre 
# atualizado.

# Variaveis
$cod_imovel = $_GET['cod_consulta'];
$data       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$visitado   = 1;

#SQL Execute
$sql        = "INSERT INTO visitados (cod_imovel, visitado, data) VALUES (:cod_imovel, :visitado, :data)";
$query  = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':cod_imovel' => $cod_imovel, ':visitado' => $visitado, ':data' => $data));

#Apagar todos os registros menos os 12 últimos

?>
```

Parece que o servidor não aceita **subquerys**... outro jeito?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a chave primária desta tabela (caso ela possua uma)?

Comment: É **id** mesmo.

Comment: Qual a versão do mysql?

Comment: A versão do MySQL é **5.1.46**

Comment: Editei minha resposta com `JOIN` como opção à suquery não suportada pela sua versão do MySql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta é uma solução bem simplificada, *sem subqueries* supondo que a ordem de *ids* seja temporal:

```
// primeiro pegamos os 12 ids mais recentes, do maior pro menor
$query = $pdo->prepare( 'SELECT id FROM visitados ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12' );
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();

// destes, pegamos o id do ultimo registro    
$ultimo = array_pop( $result );
$doze = $ultimo[0];

// agora, deletamos os menores que o id obtido
$query = $pdo->prepare( 'DELETE FROM visitados WHERE id < :doze' );
$query->execute( array(':doze' => $doze ) );
```

O que pode acontecer em um caso de *race condition* é alguem inserir um registro entre uma das duas *queries*, e por algum breve momento você ter mais que doze recentes temporariamente, até nova consulta.

<sup><sub>**Nota:** tenho a impressão que deve ter um monte de jeito mais sensato de chegar no resultado que você quer sem precisar ficar deletando coisas a todo o momento, mas não vem ao caso para fins de resposta à questão.</sub></sup>

Comment: Como é uma requisição que será feita diversas vezes por diversas pessoas por dia isso que citou vai acontecer inevitavelmente.

Comment: De curiosidade, qual seria o motivo de deletar toda hora em vez de usar o LIMIT para pegar os resultados?

Comment: Porque toda vez que alguém consultar um imóvel, este será registrado no banco para ficar no **ÚLTIMOS MAIS VISUALIZADOS** e daqui a pouco vai ter 2 milhões de registros nessa base, não sei se isso afetaria o desempenho mesmo estando parando o script ao buscar os 12.

Comment: é que voce poderia apagar depois de um tempo, nao em toda consulta. Ai simplificaria, pq usaria a 1a parte da query que eu pus pra pegar os 12 mais recentes e mostrar na tela. Aí tanto faz se sobrarem 13 ou 14 ou 50 na base, pq os 12 que vc queria já foram pegos.

Comment: Pode ser, esse site vai ter cron então poderia executar esta tarefa na hora do cron, certo?

Comment: Uma vez por dia acho que ja estaria bom demais limpar a base. O segredo da query é que eu usei o DESC pra pegar invertido, ou seja, os ultimos 12. Pode trocar o id pelo campo data se preferir.

Comment: cc @MarcosViniciusNasc.Pereira O delete usando JOIN que postei na minha resposta resolve num único comando.

Answer (score 2):

Olá,
Pelo que eu entendi, você pode fazer algo assim,

Após a execução do script, vamos dizer que ele insira 100 registros, execute outro insert.

#Limpar a tabela

```
DELETE FROM <ultimos visualizados>;
```

Após insira os novos registros

```
INSERT INTO <ultimos visualizados> ([id],[bla],[bla],[DATA])
SELECT [id],[bla],[bla],STR_TO_DATE([DATA],'%Y-%m-%d') FROM <tabela dos 100 registros> ORDER BY <campo que deseja ordenar> DESC LIMIT 12;
```

Espero ter ajudado. :D

Comment: Votei na sua resposta mas ele não me ajuda porque não quero criar **ultimos visualizados** mas obrigado. Pesoal, parece que o mysql da kinghost não aceita **subquerys**.

Comment: Qual é o objetivo da query que você deseja?

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que os "últimos" sejam determinados pelo campo data e que o campo data seja único, você pode excluir todos que não estejam entre as últimas 12 datas:

```
delete from 
    visitados 
where
    data not in (
        select data
        from visitados
        order by data desc
        limit 12)
```

Ou, considerando que você possui uma chave primária Id como você postou em seu comentário:

```
delete from 
    visitados 
where
    id not in (
        select id
        from visitados
        order by data desc
        limit 12)
```

Dado que a versão do seu MySql não suporta `LIMIT` em subqueries, você pode usá-lo em um `LEFT JOIN` deletando todos os registros que não sejam "marcados para serem mantidos", ou seja, deletando todos os que os registros que não estejam entre os últimos 12:

```
delete visitados.* 
from visitados
    left join (
        select id, 'sim' as manter 
        from visitados
        order by data desc
        limit 12) 
        as v2 on v2.id = visitados.id
where v2.manter is null;
```

Testado: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/3eeb4/1/0.

Answer (score 2):

Use uma subquery com os IDs do imóvel dentro de um `NOT IN` combinado com um `DELETE` (supondo que sua tabela visitados tem uma chave primária).

```
DELETE FROM visitados WHERE id_visita NOT IN (
    SELECT id_visita 
    FROM visitados 
    ORDER BY data DESC 
    LIMIT 12
)
```

Ele manterá somente os 12 últimos da query interna. Você pode aplicar outros filtros caso você deseje no seu `DELETE`.

```
DELETE FROM visitados WHERE cod_imovel = 15 AND id_visita NOT IN (
    SELECT id_visita 
    FROM visitados 
    ORDER BY data DESC 
    LIMIT 12
)
```